# Quickest way to get ical email attachment into Google Calendar

Tags: email, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm running Thunderbird on Windows. I often receive .ics (iCal) attachments - invitations to meetings. Currently I save the attachment to my desktop, open Google Calendar, choose 'Add>Import Calendar', browse to the .ics file, and return to the calendar.

Is there any tool that can speed this up... e.g. I forward the email to a special email address and it automatically parses and adds the event to my google calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Lightning](http://bfish.xaedalus.net/?p=239)** gives you a plug-in way for Thunderbird to sync with Google Calendar, works both directions.  I've used it without any issues, hopefully it will do what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[Calify](http://www.califyapp.com) does just that.
It can open *.ics files in various web calendars, including Google Calendar.